# Sorting users by tags

Tags: support, tags

"Users" lists all users (ordered by weekly/monthly/../total reputation), each followed by a number of tags, related to his/her MO-activity. My question is: 
Is it possible to view the list of all users attached to one or more tags? 
Thank you.

Comment: Do you know "topusers" (per tag), like http://mathoverflow.net/tags/ag.algebraic-geometry/topusers already and want something more elaborate?

Comment: If there were a way to see beyond the first 20 entries, quid's link would seem to be an ideal answer.

Comment: There have been 91 ag.algebraic-geometry badges awarded, http://mathoverflow.net/help/badges/99/ag-algebraic-geometry with similar lists for other tags.

Comment: I hadn't thought of doing that before. It's an interesting idea, and I'll check into it.

Comment: @S.Carnahan: You can use the data explorer to go as far as you want down the list - http://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/214921/top-users-per-tag?TagName=ag.algebraic-geometry&Count=50